# Build pipeline for .NET versions older than Core

Tags: .net, azure-devops

We are looking into moving our legacy code to Azure DevOps. The codebase is using .NET version 4.5.

By looking at Azure DevOps documentation all I see are instructions to create a build pipeline for .NET v5 applications and .NET Core 3.1 is what is referred to as old .NET.

Can an Azure DevOps build pipeline be configured to use older, non-core versions of .NET? Like .NET 4.5 for example?

Comment: Yes sure, we do that all the time. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4?view=azure-devops for a start. Also, when you create a new pipeline it will show you templates for .Net Framework applications as well as .Net Core applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Azure pipeline does support building `non-sdk net framework` projects. You should choose the template like .NET Desktop(non-sdk net framework windows projects) or ASP.NET(non-sdk net framework web projects).

[image]